# Loading dialog BlackBerry Browserfield

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

How can I add an loading dialog to my Browserfield when the page is loading?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a GaugeField: net.rim.device.api.ui.component.GaugeField, 
following the example at: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Gauge_field_1303006_11.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Use `BrowserFieldListener` and use the following two functions in the class created:

```
public void documentCreated(BrowserField browserField, ScriptEngine scriptEngine, Document document) {
    try{
        System.out.println("Document Created");
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
            Dialog.alert("Loading");
            }});
    } catch (Exception ex) { }
}

public void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField, Document document) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Document loaded");
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
            Dialog.alert("Finished Loading");
            }});
    } catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```